# How Do I find Out the Username And Password Of Wifi Windows 7?

Tags: windows

Basically i have a computer that is dual booted with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. On the windows 7 side I do not have admin control. However on the Ubuntu side I have full control. So I want to know how can I find out the Username and Password of a wifi that the windows side has saved. On the Ubuntu side i have free range over the Windows C drive

Comment: Cross-posted to SU: http://superuser.com/questions/576627/where-is-the-wifi-password-stored-on-windows-7

Answer (score 4):

- Get something like Hiren's boot CD and burn it from ubuntu or windows
- Boot into the environment to [Reset the admin account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIx46zQlKCk) or add a new administrator account using [this hack](http://www.technibble.com/bypass-windows-logons-utilman/) directly from within Ubuntu.
- Boot into Windows and Log in with your newly created or reset account
- Download and run [THIS software](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) from Nirsoft as administrator under Windows 7.
- You should now have the password.

Hope that helps